# FFmpeg 0.6 fails to build on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, build, ffmpeg

I am trying to build ffmpeg 0.6 for a project I have. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and when I try to build it I get the following error:

```
In file included from libavcodec/mpegvideo.h:32:0,
              from libavcodec/vaapi_internal.h:30,
              from libavcodec/vaapi_mpeg4.c:23:
libavcodec/get_bits.h: In function ‘skip_bits’:
libavcodec/get_bits.h:387:17: warning: variable ‘re_cache’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       OPEN_READER(re, s)
                   ^ 
libavcodec/get_bits.h:135:13: note: in definition of macro ‘OPEN_READER’
     int name##_cache= 0;\
         ^
libavcodec/vaapi_mpeg4.c: In function ‘vaapi_mpeg4_start_frame’:
libavcodec/vaapi_mpeg4.c:89:73: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ff_h263_get_gob_height’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
pic_param->num_macroblocks_in_gob           = s->mb_width * ff_h263_get
                                                            ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
common.mak:40: recipe for target 'libavcodec/vaapi_mpeg4.o' failed
make: *** [libavcodec/vaapi_mpeg4.o] Error 1
```

I faced a similar error with ffserver.o file but i downloaded these files here and it fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev \
libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev \
libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config texinfo zlib1g-dev
```

I believe its something similar. Anybody has any ideas?? 
Thank you.

Comment: Whats the reason for attempting to compile a 6 year old version of ffmpeg?

Comment: As I said its for my dissertation project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've built a 0.6 version on my ubuntu 16.04.

The error `implicit declaration of function` means some symbol can be found in some header, but this very header is not included in that source file.

So that I tried finding the `ff_h263_get_gob_height` function declaration:

```
$ ag ff_h263_get_gob_height
```

And it turns out it is declared in "libavcodec/h263.h". All you need to do is add a line to `libavcodec/vaapi_mpeg4.c`:

```
#include "libavcodec/h263.h"
```

There will be another similar error when continuing to build.

Also you have to configure the project with `--enable-pthreads`, otherwise the linker will complain about some annoying DSO error.